# Run bash command in python script for X seconds

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpsd

I have a gps hooked up to my raspberry pi and am trying to use it to geotag photos from an incoming camera. By issuing the command "gpsd -nND2 /dev/ttyUSB0," I can get bash echo outputs of continuous gps data that can later be parsed. I only need to average 10 data points or so (collected over 10 seconds), however, and want to close gpsd down after that.

My general timelapse program is written in python, so this is what I have so far:

```
(stdout, stderr) = Popen(["gpsd","-nND2,"/dev/ttyUSB0"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()
```

Unfortunately, this would output to variable *stdout* an unlimited number of data points that I can't parse. The output is much like a never-ending ping routine. How can I stop the data collection to make for a reasonable/parsable data dump?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://catb.org/gpsd/gpsd.html), you should *not* be looking at the console output, and instead using `gpsd` as a **d**aemon, communicating to it via TCP:

> Client applications will communicate with gpsd via a TCP/IP port, 2947 by default).

Comment: there is a python gps module made just for gpsd. thanks for pointing me on the right track

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?  I've not tested it.

```
proc = Popen(["gpsd","-nND2","/dev/ttyUSB0"], stdout=PIPE)

samples = []
for _ in range(10):
    samples.append(proc.stdout.readline())

proc.terminate()
```

Comment: When I run this, it does not terminate gpsd. The only way I know how to get it to stop is to Ctrl+Shift+C it.

Comment: replace the `terminate` method with the `kill` method. Or send the proc `SIGINT`.  Have a look at Eric's solution- I'm not versed with `gpsd` but it sounds like it has a socket for communication (via his response). That would be the correct way if the daemon supports it.